# Equivalent of Fragment (Android) in iOS

Tags: ios, android-fragments, viewcontroller

I want to know if there is a way to use some view controllers within a view controller which provides the same functionality as `Fragment`s in Android?
I want to use custom view controllers so I do not want to use `NSTabViewController`, `UISplitViewController` etc.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`Container View Controllers` allow to include child view controller inside another view controller. Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html) by clicking on the "more..." link in the class overview.

> **Implementing a Container View Controller**
>   A custom UIViewController subclass can also act as a container view controller. A container view controller manages the presentation of content of other view controllers it owns, also known as its child view controllers. A child's view can be presented as-is or in conjunction with views owned by the container view controller....

Using them in storyboards is as simple as dragging the Container View to your view controller.

[image]

And Xcode will automatically add a child view controller to it

[image]

Comment: `Container View` is not available when using Xib's though. My approach is to add a view controller in code by calling `- (void)addChildViewController:(UIViewController *)childController;` -> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621394-addchildviewcontroller

Comment: This answer gives you also a hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32554359 and the Apple documentation can help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13