# Add a ContainerView inside a UIViewController created from .xib

Tags: objective-c, xib, uicontainerview

I have a .xib file and i want to add it a container view (to place inside a ViewController). Unfortunately a container view is only disposable by storyboard. But when i create a .xib file and i search for the container view controller, i don´t found it. Can someone give me a tips how to achieve my task?

Comment: it is not possible as it needs to deal with parent and child view relationship which is not meant for xib

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you're using a `xib` instead of a `storyboard`, you can just add a plain `UIView` to the `xib` to act as a container. Then in code, add your childViewController's `view` as a subview of the container. Here, I've followed the appropriate child view controller methods and added layout constraints to ensure its frame updates with the container's frame:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIViewController *childViewController = ...; // create your child view controller

    [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
    [self.containerView addSubview:childViewController.view];
    [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    NSArray *horzConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[childView]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:@{@"childView" : childViewController.view}];

    NSArray *vertConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[childView]|"
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:@{@"childView" : childViewController.view}];

    [self.view addConstraints:horzConstraints];
    [self.view addConstraints:vertConstraints];

    childViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}
```

Comment: Getting error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
Unable to interpret '|' character, because the related view doesn't have a superview 
H:|[childView]| 
              ^'

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal it is added to a superview in the line `[self.containerView addSubview:childViewController.view];`. Probably your `containerView` is nil. Check your IBOutlet.

Answer (score 3):

Check this:

```
SelectDateViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"selectDateVCID"];
[self addChildViewController:vc];
[vc.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.selectDateContainerView.frame.size.width, self.selectDateContainerView.frame.size.height)];
[self.selectDateContainerView addSubview:vc.view];
[vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```