# Can't find Container View Object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, uicontainerview

Am I the only one who can't find the Container View object in Xcode 7??

I used this feature before and now I want to implement it again an I can't find it.

I was wondering if maybe now is deprecated but it's still on Apple official documentation.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html

[image]

What I'm trying to do is to reproduce Snapchat navigation view, I'm having an scrollView with paging that will contain 3 View Controllers on each page. I want to use the container to add every child view controller.

Comment: Which Xcode version you are using.. 7.1 or 7.2 ?

Comment: @RajTandel 7.2.1 and not using storyboards

Comment: You cannot use container view with xib. check this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549731/add-a-containerview-inside-a-uiviewcontroller-created-from-xib . Hope this will help you out.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To echo the answer that user Raj Tandel posted in a comment, apparently you cannot use container views with xibs.

[Here is a great thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32549731/add-a-containerview-inside-a-uiviewcontroller-created-from-xib) that explains why:

> **It is not possible as it needs to deal with parent and child view relationship which is not meant for xib(s)**

The solution is to "just add a plain UIView to the xib to act as a container. Then in code, add your child view controller's view as a subview of the container"

For further info, click the included link above (in an effort to keep good answers and threads continuous, rather than repeating what already exists)